# How do I make a text box show the text from a notepad document

Tags: c#

I have saved a .txt file from notepad in the debug/bin folder.
I'm supposed to be able to click a button on the form and it will show what was written in that .txt file in a textbox but I don't know how to do it.
is there a specific type of text box, because the one on the example is a square but when it won't let me edit mine?

Comment: Answer to part 1 below. I have no idea what you are asking in part two. There is a TextBox, and a RichTextBox. That's about it. I'm sure I can help if you can provide an example or more details.

Comment: What kind of project is this? Windows Forms?

Comment: which example are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ReadAllText` static method of the `File` class is perfect for this:

```
txtDisplay.Text = File.ReadAllText("myTestFile.txt");
```

Because your file is already in the project output folder, you don't need any special paths. The function does what you would think; it reads all the text in the file and stuffs it into a string. You then assign this string to your textbox!